# django xml generate object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, xml, django, django-models

This is the error i am getting

> Exception Type:AttributeError
>   Exception Value:'MessageHeaderModel2' object has no attribute 'get'

I want to generate xml file based on the model instance

This is my model view

> def genxmlview(request):
>           data = serializers.serialize("xml", MessageHeaderModel2.objects.all())
>           with open("file.xml", "w") as out:
>                   xml_serializer.serialize(SomeModel.objects.all(), stream=out)

According to [djnago serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) i did this code. But y i am getting the error

This is my modified code

> def genxmlview(request):
>           data = serializers.serialize('xml', MessageHeaderModel2.objects.all())
>           with open("file.xml", "w") as out:
>                   out.write(data)
>           out.close()

Comment: Think this error may be raised somewhere else than in the code you're showing us. In any case, note that you still have a reference to 'SomeModel' in your code, last line of genxmlview.

Comment: Ok .. see if i change somemodel to MessageHeaderModel2 .. Then also showing the same error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

def genxmlview(request):

```
data = serializers.serialize("xml", MessageHeaderModel2.objects.all())
with open("file.xml", "w") as out:
     out.write(data)
out.close()
```

---

I don't understand the second call to serialize() in your code.
You get the serialized data in the first line of the function.
You then want to write it out to a file?

As per the previous comment, it is likely that the error is raised elsewhere ...

Comment: Now .. ** name 'data' is not defined ** error is coming

Comment: That looks ok. Please post the full backtrace.